# How to display results on same page as requesting page in jsp-servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I developing this web app using jsp and servlets. I was wondering how to display results on same page as on from which the request was made. For example, usually what I do is that a request is sent from one jsp to a servlet and then servlet sends the response/results on separate jsp. I am want to show a database results on same page. How can this be done?..A code snippet would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Using Jabascript, you can send Ajax request to the servlet, retrieve the response and show results on the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the necessary data in the request scope and use [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) to forward the control to the desired JSP which in turn can generate the appropriate HTML based on the results.

```
request.setAttribute("results", results);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

This is also demonstrated in the hello world examples in [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Answer (score 2):

That's totally posible, but you need to include JavaScript in your toolset. What I'm suggesting is an AJAX approach in your application, and that implies intensive use of client-side scripting (i.e JavaScript).

[This tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ajax1/) from DeveloperWorks makes a pure JavaScript/Servlet approach. If you want to do more advanced stuff, I strongly suggest you to use a JavaScript Framework with AJAX support, like [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: It's absolutely not that hard. It's even easier than when using ajax.

Comment: Easy and hard are all relative. I'll remove adjectives to remain objective

Answer (score 0):

From your servlet, send a redirect to your same page. Also, set some attributes in request and show it in your page, e.g. save `List<MyObject>` in request, then in your jsp read the list from request and show the values in a table.

Comment: The session scope is not the right scope to hold request scoped data.